# Why this in OOP

Tags: java, oop

```
class Parent {

    private int var = 1;

    public int getVar() {
        return var;
    }

    public void setVar(int var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

}

class Child extends Parent {

    private int var = 2;

    public int getVar() {
        return var;
    }

    public void setVar(int var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

}
```

And now, when testing it, we get 2.

```
Child child = new Child();
Parent parent = (Parent)child;
System.out.println(parent.getVar());
```

I am casting the child object to a Parent explicitly and making my intentions clear 
why then when i do parent.getVar() i get 2 ?

Comment: You are casting child to a Parent, which is entirely acceptable since it extends it, but you aren't initializing it as such. You have to initialize a Parent variable  explicitly, not just cast to it. Since child is initialized as a Child, it's var will == var from Child. If you want Child methods to perform and return Parent methods you need to override the method and call super.methodName(methodParams);

Comment: This is one of my favorite aspects of OOP, take a look at [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Child child = new Child();
Parent parent = (Parent)child;
```

You are simply using a super class reference to point. Your object is still of class `Child` and that will never change. So you would always get `2`.

So when you call

```
System.out.println(parent.getVar());
```

at compile time it checks whether `getVar()` is present in class of reference `Parent` which is true. So it compiles. At runtime it knows the class of actual object which is `Child` and executes corresponding method.

Comment: mention a little bit about polymorphism as well.

Comment: Hi Aniket your line in the answer "Your object is still of class Child" nails the question .A unrelated  question mind telling me what software you used in your blog to create the pic in the post "How to sort a Map on the values in Java?"

Answer (score 1):

Your object is `Child` here. But you are using `Parent` super class reference. At runtime, the object is of type `Child`, hence your code calling the child method results in getting `2`.

Answer (score 0):

The child getVar has overwritten the parent getVar method so even though your reference is typed as the parent, it's still the child and so still returns 2.

Having a known reference to the Child class you could have a special method on the child to access the parent var:

```
class Child extends Parent {

    ... 

    public int getParentVar() {
        return super.getVar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reading my "mind" and answering probably my next question :)

Answer (score 0):

All methods in Java are virtual. That means that the reference type does not matter, what matters is the object type. You clearly have a reference to `Child` object, this is why `Child`'s `getVar()` method is being executed.

What is even more fun to realize, that you have two different fields with name  `var`, one in `Parent` and one in `Child` classes.

Comment: Hi two different fields with the name  var was deliberate this is a tricky question kinda of one gets asked in a Interview

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly the idea of OO: you can have different "childs" extending one parent with  different implementations of methods (override) and in runtime the implementation that is called will be of the current object (polymorphism), regardless what you casted it to: during runtime the variables/class members will be read from the 'current' environment (the child in our case).

The use of such behavior (polymorphism) can be demonstrated with the following:

```
abstract class Shape {    
    abstract public double getArea();
}

class Square extends Shape {
    double edge = 2.0;
    public double getArea() {
        return edge * edge;
    }
}

class Circle extends Shape {
    double radius = 2.0;
    public double getArea() {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }
}

public class TestShapes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape[] shapeArray = new Shape[2];
        shapeArray[0] = new Square();
        shapeArray[1] = new Circle();

        for (Shape p: shapeArray) {
            // every shape "knows" how to calculate its own area
            // there's no need to find out which type of shape is it
            // and there's no need to cast anything!
            System.out.println("Area: " + p.getArea());
        }
    }
}
```

That said, if you want to call from the child to a parent-method (which is a bad practice!) you can do it using `super` keyword:

```
class Child extends Parent {    
    private int var = 2;    
    public int getVar() {
        return super.getVar();
    }
}

// usage:
Child c = new Child();
System.out.println(c.getVar()); // will print "1"
```

Comment: Brilliant answer alfasin thanks a ton time for me to get hold of poly mor phism :)