# Instance of a class inheritance

Tags: java, object, inheritance, instance

I am currently studying java. I have a question about inheritance.
I am aware you can inherit the variables of the parent class using:

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
}
```

However, i wanted to do somethin like inheriting the variables and the values assigned to them from an instance of the ParentClass. Example: i have a class Animal and a class Dog extending from Animal. The class animal has:

```
private int number_of_legs;
private int number_of_eyes;
```

At this point i create a new instance of the class animal:

```
Animal first_animal = new Animal(4,2); 
/*where 4 and 2 are the number of legs and eyes which 
 *i attribute through a constructor present in Animal.
 */
```

Now i want to create a new instance of the class Dog which inherits the values from the instance of the class Animal i just created (first_animal).

```
Dog first_dog = new ??? // i tried with ...new first_animal.Dog but it didn't work.
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
Dog dog = new Dog(4, 2);
```

You cannot create an instance of a subclass as an instance of a super class. You can say that all `Dog`s are `Animal`s, but not that all `Animal`s are `Dog`s.

Note that the statement above means:

```
//valid and accepted because one kind of instance of animal is a dog
Animal dog = new Dog(4, 2);
//invalid and throws a compiler error because one kind of instance of a Dog cannot be any animal
Dog anotherDog = new Animal(4, 2);
```

---

`new Animal.Dog` is wrong here because it means that you have a `static class Dog` inside `Animal` class. `new first_animal.Dog` is wrong here because it means that you have an inner class `Dog` inside `Animal` class. Those are different topics you should not cover **yet**.

Answer (score 1):

You pass the values from the constructor of the sub-class to the constructor of the super-class.

```
Dog firstDog = new Dog (4,2);
```

The Dog constructor would look like this :

```
public Dog (int legs, int eyes) 
{
   super (legs,eyes);
}
```

If you wish to create an instance of a sub-class Dog from an instance of the super-class Animal, you can use a copy constructor :

```
public Dog (Animal animal) 
{
    super (animal.getLegs(), animal.getEyes());
}
```

Then you can use it with :

```
Dog firstDog = new Dog (firstAnimal);
```

Comment: @starf this example of copy constructor is a bad idea. It means that you can create a `Dog` instance from any `Animal`, like a `Fly` or an `Octopus`, unless you have an *octopus-dog* pet :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I understand your example :), but surely this is answering the original question, seeing that Fly is an Animal, and Octopus is an Animal?

Comment: @starf By [octopus - wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octopus): *The octopus (/ˈɒktəpʊs/ or /ˈɒktəpəs/; plural: octopuses, octopi, or octopodes; see below) is a cephalopod mollusc of the order Octopoda.*. It has a link to [mollusc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollusc): *The molluscs or mollusks[note 1] /ˈmɒləsks/ compose the large phylum of invertebrate **animals** known as the Mollusca.*. So yes, octopus are animals :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't inherit `private` variables and methods. If you want to inherit them you have to change the access to `protected`.

A bit about OO and *real* life: every dog is an animal - but not every animal is a dog, which means that you *can* do:

```
Animal animal = new Dog(4,2);
```

but you can't do vice versa:

```
Dog dog = new Animal(4,2); // compilation error
```

Comment: Can you explain a little further the first statement? What does the code exactly do? is animal an Animal or a Dog?

Comment: @user3900065 actually, I explained it yesterday [*here*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072736/why-this-in-oop/25072778#25072778)

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that your instance fields are labeled `private` in your superclass.  This restricts their scope to that class, eliminating them from any subclasses.  If you would like to expand the scope to subclasses while restricting it otherwise, call the instance fields `protected`.

Your second problem is that you can't be initializing a new instance of the subclass when the instance already has a class type.  What you can do, however, is write:

```
Animal first_dog = new Dog(4, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an instance of Dog which "inherits" from a specific instance of class Animal.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make your class Animal abstract and set the scope of its attributes to protected instead of private if you need to re-use them in subclasses. To instantiate an Animal, just call the constructor of a concrete subclass of Animal (need to define at least one constructor which calls a superclass constructor as its first statement).

Comment: You don't need to mark your classes as `abstract` nor you need to mark all the fields (attributes) to `protected` in order to enable inheritance.

Comment: I know, but in that case it is the obvious class hierarchy I would use. What would mean an Animal among Cats, Dogs and Rats ? For the fields, I specified that it was only for those he wants to re-use in subclasses. You could say that he can still let it private and define getters and setters, but in that particular case I don't think it would be relevant, it would only make the code more verbose.

Comment: Well, if you go so theoretical, what about a non-discovered animal? It is an animal but you don't know to which specie belongs, but it's still an animal :)

Comment: It's a bit far-fetched, isn't it ? I don't want to debate for hours wether it is better to make it abstract or not, let's just say that in 90% of the cases that's the natural choice for an Animal class. As this is a very common pratice to factorize constructors and attributes in an abstract superclass I thought it was good to mention it.

Comment: *in 90% of the cases that's the natural choice for an Animal class* no, you're completely wrong. In fact, you should not make a class abstract unless you have specific reasons to do so. And I don't find a good specific reason in your post or comments to make it abstract, so leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I came here with the same question you were posing.  After reading the answers provided, and thinking about it further I realized what I needed to do.

Say you have an Array of `Animals`, of which one is a Dog.  I want to take the attributes from the `Animal[0]` instance and build a `Pet`.

You would pass the `Animal[0]` into the build method.

```
public Pet (Animal animal,String name){
     this.Legs = animal.Legs;
     this.Tail = animal.Tail;
     this.Species = animal.Species;
     etc....
     this.Name = name
}
```

So while the Pet object isn't "inheriting" the variables from the Animal instance, it will be taking on its values.